# Null hypothesis of regression = grand mean of data?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mean

This is a very simplistic question, but is the "grand mean of the data" another name for the null hypothesis of regression? This horizontal straight line (slope of zero) is what we are comparing our model to, to see if it's a better fit?

Comment: It would help if you said what the null hypothesis of your regression is. (There is a sense in which what you write is true, and that forms the basis of $R^2$, but your exact null hypothesis will matter.)

Comment: @Dave could you share this case?

Comment: If we are predicting the conditional mean, the most naïve sensible way to guess is to guess the pooled mean, which is an intercept-only linear regression. $R^2$ compares the variance of this intercept-only model to the more complicated model.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @Dave would the null hypothesis model be $y = \beta_0 + \epsilon$ in that case?

Comment: @jros Something like that...I would phrase it as $\beta_1=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**

But it depends on what you mean by "the null hypothesis of regression".

Software packages like `R` give an overall test of the regression. This is testing if any of the non-intercept parameters are nonzero.

$$
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 +\cdots+\beta_px_p + \epsilon\\
H_0: \beta_1=\cdots=\beta_p=0\\
H_a: H_0\text{ is false}
$$

When we do the test, we are comparing the regression equation above to an alternative that does not consider any predictors:

$$
y = \beta_0 +\epsilon
$$

If we fit this model, we fill find that $\hat\beta_0 = \bar y$, where $\bar y$ is the grand mean of all of the $y$ observations. That grand mean tends to go by the "pooled" mean of $y$ for the empirical setting or the "marginal" mean of $y$ for the theoretical setting (though "marginal" also works for the

Thus, there is a sense in which the null hypothesis of a regression has an equivalence with the grand mean of all $y$ observations.

Comment: But there is also a case when it not true?

Comment: @Nate When what is not true?

Comment: You mentioned it depends on what I mean by the null hypothesis of regression. I thought your definition was the only null hypothesis. I don't quite understand when the grand mean wouldn't be the null hypothesis of regression.

Comment: @Nate Without further clarification, I would take “the null hypothesis of the regression” to mean the hypothesis tested with the F-test in the R summary. However, nothing keeps you from testing other nested regression models, such as a model with a continuous predictor vs a model with that continuous predictor plus a factor variable (ANCOVA). In that case, the null hypothesis would be that the coefficients on the factor levels all equal zero vs at least one not equaling zero. However, both models assume the continuous predictor might have a nonzero coefficient.

Comment: Got it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The *Grand Mean* of the data is the pooled average of a parameter.

The basic null hypothesis of linear regression for the relationship: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x+\epsilon$,

is $H_0:\beta_1 = 0$.

If you were to consider $x$ to be a categorical variable, then the *Grand Mean* **and** *Pooled Variance* could be used as evidence against the null hypothesis, but in short, **No, the *Grand Mean* is not synonymous with the null hypothesis for regression**

Comment: Please explain "average of a parameter"

Comment: The grand mean is the mean, or average, of all values, regardless of the group they belong to (i.e. if I had a dataset with time stamps of 2000 - 2021, I would have a mean for each year, and a grand mean where I average the data over all years). In this case the mean is the parameter.

Comment: @JTH, just to supplement Nate's answer, a parameter in this context is a characteristic of a population. For example: age, weight, or height

Comment: I won’t downvote, but you might want to read my answer.